# How do I make a christmas tree in pygame with this code?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a christmas tree in pygame but I cannot figure it out.

The window opens, but then closes again immeadiately.

```
import pygame

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
GREEN = ( 0, 0, 255)
BROWN = ( 160, 82, 45)

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame window")
done = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      done = True
  screen.fill(WHITE)  
  # Code here 
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, BROWN, (350 - 10, 250, 10, 250))
  pygame.draw.lines(screen, GREEN, TRUE, (100,100), (150,200), 1)

  pygame.display.flip()

  clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi! I see that you are a new contributor. Welcome to StackOverflow!
Your question can be improved to be better understood by others. It seems to me that you are having issues oppening the PyGame window. This has no relation to your end app : the christmas tree.
You should rephrase your question to something like "Issues with PyGame : windows closes immediately".
Thanks !

Comment: I strongly recommend the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a few fundamental syntax errors.

The main code is looping `while not done`, but `done` initially starts at `True`, so it exists without ever doing anything.

In python the logical (Boolean) value is `True` not `TRUE`.  (I really wish it was `true` myself.)  Obviously it's counterpart is `False`.

The other significant issue is that the `pygame.draw.lines()` function takes a list of co-ordinates.

Oh, and the code redefined `GREEN` to be a blue-colour, I assume this is meant to be `BLUE`.

I moved the rectangle for the trunk, and the list of points for the tree, out of the main loop into constants.  This allows them to be changed separately, without having to confuse the main loop with a huge list of points.

```
import pygame

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED   = ( 255, 0, 0)
BLUE  = ( 0, 0, 255)        # <-- Not 'GREEN' again
BROWN = ( 160, 82, 45)

TRUNK_RECT  = [ 350-10, 250, 10, 250 ]      # Rectangle x,y,width,height
TREE_POINTS = [ (100,100), (150,200) ]      # list of points for tree polygon

pygame.init()
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame window")
done = False                                    # <-- Was True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    # Handle Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # Code here 
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen, BROWN, (350 - 10, 250, 10, 250) )
    pygame.draw.rect( screen, BROWN, TRUNK_RECT )
    #pygame.draw.lines(screen, GREEN, True, [ (100,100), (150,200)], 1)   # <-- Needs a list of points
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, GREEN, True, TREE_POINTS, 1)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Obviously you need to work out further co-ordinates for the tree.

It would be a better (but more complicated) approach to draw the tree scaled to fit in the window. Put the window dimensions into constants (e.g.: `WINDOW_WIDTH` & `WINDOW_HEIGHT`), and draw things to percentages of these values.  For example the trunk might now be:

```
TRUNK_WIDTH  = WINDOW_WIDTH // 20                  # 5% of screen width
TRUNK_HEIGHT = WINDOW_HEIGHT // 4                  # 25% of screen height
TRUNK_RECT   = [ WINDOW_WIDTH//2-TRUNK_WIDTH//2,   # x-pos = Middle of the window
                 WINDOW_HEIGHT-TRUNK_HEIGHT,       # y-pos = Trunk at Bottom 
                 TRUNK_WIDTH, TRUNK_HEIGHT ]
```